# Rates of convergence numerical analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, rate-of-convergence

I have been leaning about fixed point iterations, and have been introduced to the notion of rates of convergence, in the quadratic, and linear case. Consider a fixed point iteration $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$, then the iteration converges linearly if $|x_{n+1} - \alpha| \leq C|x_n - \alpha|$, $C > 0$, and quadratically if $|x_{n+1} - \alpha| \leq K|x_n - \alpha|^2$, $K > 0$.

Are there any different rates of convergence? What are examples of say, sequences that converge, but neither quadratically nor linearly?

Thank you.

Comment: you can use all possible non negative exponents...

Comment: @fonfonx What are some examples, say, of sequences that converge with rate $r \geq 3$ but do not converge linearly or quadratically?

Comment: and in your example C should be less than 1

Comment: if you converge at rate r >= 3 then the error is less than 1 from a certain rank and therefore $|x_n -\alpha|^3 \leq |x_n-\alpha|^2$ and you converge quadratically...

Comment: @fonfonx So there are no examples of sequences which converge neither quadratically nor linearly?

Comment: you can have logarithmic convergence rates

Comment: The convergence rate of the secant method is the golden mean $\frac{1+\sqrt5}2=1.6…$

Comment: There are plenty of examples out there of widely varying convergence rates. The more interesting question is about *algorithms* that give different convergence rates. And for this, things other than linear and quadratic can be a bit hard to find. The secant method is one example, giving a rate in between linear and quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

Try $x_n := x^{3^n}$ with $0<x<1$ converging cubicly to zero.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comments you may want to have a look at http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~amos/412/lecture-notes/lecture03.pdf and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence